# What is best way to convert this with JSON data in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React TreeView right now I'm using as static but now I want to use this with JSON format how can I done this?

**My Code:-**

ratHelper.js

```js
const getData = () => {
    return [
        {
            "tree": {
              "content": "main",
              "type": "L1",
              "tree": [
                {
                  "content": "subtree with children",
                  "type": "L2",
                 },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                },
                {
                  "content": "hello",
                  "type": "L2"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
    ]
}

export default {getData}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Tree from "react-animated-tree";
import "./rat.css";
import helper from "./ratHelper";

const treeStyles = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: 40,
  left: 40,
  color: "white",
  fill: "white",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100vh",
  overflow: "auto",
};

const typeStyles = {
  fontSize: "5em",
  verticalAlign: "middle",
};

const data = helper.getData();
console.log(data);

const ReactAnimatedTree = () => (
  <>
  {/* {data.map((p)=>{
    <Tree>{p}</Tree>
  })} */}
    <Tree content="main" type="L1" canHide open style={treeStyles}>
      <Tree content="subtree with children" type="L2">
        <Tree content="sub-subtree with children" type="L3">
          <Tree content="child 1" type="L4">
            <Tree content="child 1" type="L5">
              <Tree content="child 1" type="L6">
                <Tree content="child 1" type="L7">
                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L8">
                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L9">
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10">
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11">
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12">
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13">
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14">
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15">
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16">
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17">
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18">
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19">
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L20" />
                                        </Tree>
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L19" />
                                      </Tree>
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L18" />
                                    </Tree>
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                    <Tree content="child 1" type="L17" />
                                  </Tree>
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                  <Tree content="child 1" type="L16" />
                                </Tree>
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                                <Tree content="child 1" type="L15" />
                              </Tree>
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                              <Tree content="child 1" type="L14" />
                            </Tree>
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                            <Tree content="child 1" type="L13" />
                          </Tree>
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                          <Tree content="child 1" type="L12" />
                        </Tree>
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                        <Tree content="child 1" type="L11" />
                      </Tree>
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                      <Tree content="child 1" type="L10" />
                    </Tree>
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                    <Tree content="hello" type="L9" />
                  </Tree>
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                  <Tree content="hello" type="L8" />
                </Tree>
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
                <Tree content="hello" type="L7" />
              </Tree>
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
              <Tree content="hello" type="L6" />
            </Tree>
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
            <Tree content="hello" type="L5" />
          </Tree>
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
          <Tree content="hello" type="L4" />
        </Tree>
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
        <Tree content="hello" type="L3" />
      </Tree>

      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />
      <Tree content="hello" type="L2" />

      {/* <Tree content="hello" canHide /> */}
    </Tree>
  </>
);

export default ReactAnimatedTree;
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: yes I want to convert all the TreeData in JSON format

Comment: That sentence doesnt really mean much. JSON is a string format, when you say "convert all the TreeData" - what do you actually mean? What have you tried in order to solve your problem? What do you want the resulting JSON to look like? IS that what you ACTUALLY meant or did you really mean you want to create your `Tree` elements from JSON? Its so unclear what your ACTUAL question is!

Comment: So, you want to convert the HTML structure to JSON

Comment: yes convert the HTML structure to JSON

Comment: well, what's the root element? from there it's simple code

Comment: I tried with `{data.map((p)=>{<Tree>{p}</Tree> })}` but this code is commented for now.

Comment: what's `data`? you've got HTML and you want to convert it to JSON ... you'll need a starting HTMLElement, then from there it's an easy recursive function to convert the elements into an Object, which you then can convert to JSON by using JSON.stringify - what's the required format of the JSON?

Comment: actually I have JSON data code but not able to add here

Comment: Why? Without your JSON its near impossible to help you!

Comment: Oh, you want JSON=>HTML not HTML=>JSON .... well, that's really simple, all you need to do is post a sample of the JSON - then it'll be relatively easy solution

Comment: I have added JSON file too in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to know how to map the JSON data in react. Here is how. This is your JSON format. I re-wrote it, so you won't mistake the data structure. It should be array.

```
const data = [
    {
      tree: {
        content: "main",
        type: "L1",
        tree: [
          {
            content: "subtree with children",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
          {
            content: "hello",
            type: "L2",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ];

export default data;

<div>
    {data.map((tree,index)=> (
        <Tree type={tree?.type} key={index} content={tree?.content}>
            {tree?.tree.map((subTree,index)=> (
                <Tree type={subTree?.type} key={index} content={subTree?.content}>
                    // you can continue map more subSubTree
                </Tree>
            ))}
        </Tree>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: tree.tree.map is not a function

Comment: are you sure you have similar data structure i showed?

Comment: yes exact data i;m using.

Comment: its working now I need to use tree?.tree.tree.map